# Misunderstanding on a question about Hawkes process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, point-processes

I think I am missing something on an exercise about Hawkes process. Here is the context :

> Let $h:\mathbb{R}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}h(t)dt<\infty$ and let $\mu>0$. We consider $N$ and $\bar{N}$ be the associated Hawkes processes having intensity

$$
\lambda(t)=\mu+\sum_{n:T_n<t}h(t-T_n)\quad\text{and}\quad \bar{\lambda}(t)=\frac{\mu}{2}+\sum_{n:\bar{T}_n<t}h(t-\bar{T}_n)
$$

The question is to prove that $N_t\geq\bar{N}_t$ a.s.

My question is the following : why the underlying point process $T_i$ is not the same for these two Hawkes processes ?

As it is written, I cannot see how to properly compare theses processes since the function $h$ has not the same point process given $\lambda(t)$ and $\bar{\lambda}(t)$.

Thank you a lot

Here is an attempt where I assume that the the $T_n$ and $\bar{T}_n$ are the same, otherwise I cannot see how to proceed.

Assume that $N_t(\omega)<\bar{N}_t(\omega)$ for some $\omega\in E$ such that $\mathbb{P}(E)>0$.

By construction of the Hawkes process, this means that at fixed $t$, there exists a set of measure positive such that $\lambda(t)(\omega)<\bar{\lambda}(t)(\omega)$ which is not possible since by construction $\lambda(t)>\bar{\lambda}(t)$ (since I assume they have the same jump as I said before starting the proof).

If someone knows how to prove this without this assumption, I would like to have a taste of this please !

Thank you

Comment: Is $h$ the same for the two processes, or should $\tilde N$ have its own $\tilde h$? (Presumably $\tilde h\le h$ to end up with the asserted inequality between $N$ and $\tilde N$.)

Comment: @JohnDawkins Yes this is the same $h$ and $\mu$.. they only differ on the point process

Comment: It looks like some condition is missing, because the hypotheses as written are symmetric in $N$ and $\tilde N$. So if the conclusion you are asked to prove is true, then $\tilde N_t\ge N_t$ a.s. would also be true, and you would have $N_t=\tilde N_t$ a.s. for all $t$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Very very sorry. The constant is not the same, I thought I updated this but no.. they are not symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition behind the Hawkes process is that immigrants arrive according to a rate-$\lambda$ Poisson process (this is for $N$). An immigrant arriving at time $u$ (say) give birth to descendants according to a non-homogeneous Poisson process of rate $h(t-u)$ for $t>u$. $N_t$ counts all arrivals or births that occurred befor time $t$. Now imagine constructing $\tilde N$ by coupling it
with $N$ as follows. Each immigrant is colored blue or orange according to the toss of a fair coin (different tosses for each immigrant). The $\tilde N$ process is constructed using only the blue immigrants–its immigration rate will be $\lambda/2$! Because the orange immigrants don't contribute to $\tilde N$, it is clear that, so constructed, $\tilde N_t\le N_t$ for all $t$, almost surely.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer I really appreciate the way of explaining this. To be sure to have understand, this means that the constant in the intensity function represent the rate of arrivals of immigrants ? Can we match this intuition with the graphical one ? That is a straight line in the cartesian plane to represent $\lambda$ and another below to represent $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ ?